# Jade select field populating data

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Is there any better ways to populate Jade based select fields, I am currently using this example. Is there any better ways to not ruin the template code?

the item value is 'day' example.

```
    select
      repeation = [ 'no-repeat', 'day', 'week', 'month']
      for item in repeation
        if job.repeat == item
          option(selected="true") #{item}
        else
          option #{item}
```

Also what about displaying multiple selections, when the item is array of ['day', 'week']?

// Edit small possible solution for multiple element

```
      enginges = [ 'google', 'bing', 'yahoo', 'duckduckgo']
      for engine in enginges
        option(selected=job.sources.indexOf(engine) != -1) #{engine}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
for item in repeation
  option(selected=job.repeat == item) #{item}
```

The same concept should be able to be applied to a multiple item select drop down.

Comment: Ty this works well, I edit my post to add the multiple selection also.

Comment: It's just javascript. The "job.repeat == item" returns true or false. The same concept can be applied when returning values from functions, you can just return the expression directly.

Comment: This works perfectly. I don't know why though - I thought the html for selected was just "<option selected>" not "<option selected='true'>" ??

Comment: @DanielM you are right. HTML5 supports only `selected` and `selected="selected"`. But. It's Jade. And it's all about JavaScript. It's correct to write `el.selected = true`. The thing is: Jade compiles `option(selected=job.repeat == item) #{item}` to `<option selected="selected">day</option>` if `job.repeat = "day"`.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things to add to the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10368381/870274):

1. "each" is more commonly used now instead of "for"
2. don't forget the "-" for the line: repeation = [ 'no-repeat', 'day',
   'week', 'month'] ,or you will get a compilation error.  So the final
   result would be
   (same as yours):

   ```
   select
     - repeation = [ 'no-repeat', 'day', 'week', 'month']
     each item in repeation
       option(selected=job.repeat == item) #{item}
   ```

Comment: Instead of "above / below", refer to other posts by something non-positional. Author's name, or a link to the post, say. Right now, only the question is above your answer.