# Populating a dropdown list in form with another models data in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, pug

I am trying to populate a dropdown list for a form for one of my models (cars), with data from another model (colours), but cannot seem to figure out how to do this. I need to somehow call the list of colours into the dropdown in the cars.jade file, so that when a user selects the auto-filled list I need the ObjectID to be the value of the item (which subsequently is saved as a new car.

**Cars New Form (car.jade):**

```
/* This is the bit I'm having trouble with */
select(name='carColours')
  option(value='')
  each colour in colours
    - var select=null; if (colour.title == carColours.title) select='selected';
    option(value=colour._id, selected=select)= colour.title
```

**Cars controller (cars.js):**

```
exports.new = function(req, res){
  res.render('cars/new', {
    title: 'New Car',
    event: new Car({})
  })
}
```

**Cars model (car.js):**

```
var CarSchema = new Schema({
  title: {type : String, default : '', trim : true},
  colour: {type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Colour'},
})
```

**Colours model (colour.js)**

```
var ColourSchema = new Schema({
  title: {type : String, default : '', trim : true},
  hexadecimal: {type : String, default : '', trim : true},
})

ColourSchema.statics = {

  list: function (options, cb) {
    var criteria = options.criteria || {}

    this.find(criteria)
      .sort({'title': 1}) // sort alphabetically
      .exec(cb)
  }

}
```

Comment: Please inform if any more information is required.

Comment: Where is the `colours` array in care.jade coming from? And what error are you getting exactly, if any?

Comment: I have added in the colours model (not array) and updated the description. I am not really getting any errors yet as I don't know how to approach the solution, which is why I was asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to render in cars.js needs to supply the list of colors.

```
exports.new = function(req, res){
  res.render('cars/new', {
    title: 'New Car',
    event: new Car({}),
    colours: [<list of possible colours>]
  })
}
```

The object you pass to `render` after the path to the view template is the context in which your view template operates.  If that object doesn't have the property in question (in this case `colours`), then neither will your view template.  (There is an exception to that, but it doesn't look like you're using it here).

I go into this in the latest episode of a screencast series I produce (http://www.learnallthenodes.com/episodes/9-view-templates-in-nodejs-with-jade).  I'm not sure the exact timestamp of when I hit that part.

Comment: Thanks mate, will watch your screencast when I get a chance. So, in that `[<list of possible colours>]` part, how is that populated from the colours model?

Comment: I suppose you could add the array as a static to your schema.  Something like `possibleColours: ['red','green','blue']` and then just pass it in as `colours: Colour.possibleColours`.  I'm assuming that you have a defined set of possible colours and that they aren't dynamic.  Does that help?

Comment: I'm assuming that your colours come from the `list` static function on your model.  In that case, in your route handler you'd need to call that function, and inside its callback you'd do your render call.  Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/juanpaco/8410206

Comment: And this would replace my 'new' function in the Cars controller correct? And in my cars.jade, I could leave as is do you think?

Comment: Yes, although it will expose another issue.  `carColours.title` is calling `title` on a variable `carColours` that isn't defined.  You would similarly need to pass in a reference to your `Car` instance to check against the list of colors.

Comment: Sorry, I think I made an error in my code, I'm pretty sure that select list population functionality in the cars.jade is incorrect. I think this other answer might hold the key to what I need for that particular bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362959/jade-select-field-populating-data

Comment: Sure thing.  Then yeah, the reason I called it `colours` in the route handler was because that was the variable you used in your template.  So that should function as a drop-in replacement.

Comment: Awesome, all looks good to me mate, thanks for your help. Will test it all tonight and if all good, will accept your answer.

Comment: Works a charm mate, you legend! I've accepted it, will award bounty in 12 hours when it lets me.